# adding new web service under framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net

file -> new -> website -> asp.net empty website (under .net framework 4.5) ->

right click on the website name in the solution explorer -> add new item ->

**cant find Web Service**.

when doing the exact same thing on a web site that was built under framework 4.0 **i do find Web Service**.

how come? can somebody explain it to me Please?

Comment: which visual studio version are you using?

Answer (score 10):

**Step 1:**

Add **Empty Web Project** with `.Net4.5`

[image]

**Step 2:**
Then right click your project and **Add New Item**.
Then select template type **Web->WebService**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What flavour of Visual Studio do you have? I can see everything

.NET 4.0 and 4.5
[image]

Comment: ultimate .. after changing "build-> target frame work" to 4.0 in the property pages. i can see "web service" in the new item dialog. weird.. And i cant see the picture u have published here..

Comment: Right-click on the website name in the solution explorer -> add new item -> you are doing it correctly. Search for "service" in the dialog.